# Custom CollectionView, how to get current items on ScrollingEnded

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I'm creating a custom layout collectionView, something like in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/uicollectionview#subclassing-uicollectionviewflowlayout).I have some text views outside the collectionView i would like to fill depending on the current item in the middle of the screen, i know i can get the current visible items using `CollectionView.IndexPathsForVisibleItems`. My question is how can i get to the `scrollingEnded` event or something similar so that i can call `CollectionView.IndexPathsForVisibleItems` in there and get the data i need to populate the text fields?

I tried overriding `ScrollAnimationEnded` in `MyCustomCollectionViewSource` but for some reason it never triggers. I also thought of potentially using an `SupplementaryView` but i was unable to find any sample code of it being used with custom layouts.

Comment: Could you please add some more description, possibly with images of what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `DecelerationEnded` and that solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can i get to the scrollingEnded event or something similar so that i can call CollectionView.IndexPathsForVisibleItems in there and get the data i need to populate the text fields?

There is a `Scrolled` method to use to achieve that (according to the `ContentOffset` to check whehter need to load more ), this method need is inside `UICollectionViewDelegate` .

```
public class MyCollectionDelegate : UICollectionViewDelegate {
    #region Computed Properties
    public CollectionView mCollectionView { get; set;}
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public MyCollectionDelegate (CollectionView collectionView)
    {
        // Initialize
        mCollectionView = collectionView;
    }
    #endregion

    public override void Scrolled(UIScrollView scrollView)
    {
        //base.Scrolled(scrollView);
        if (scrollView.ContentOffset.Y + scrollView.Frame.Size.Height - scrollView.ContentSize.Height > 30)
        {
            // load more data 
        }
}
```

Then setting `Delegate` for CollectionView as follow :

```
 this.collectionView.Delegate =  new MyCollectionDelegate(this.collectionView);
```

Comment: I'll try to play with it a bit more, but for now it goes in the If statement like 3-4 times so its not reliable to be "scrolling ended". I'll give an update if I get it to work.

Comment: @cymenx Great , look forward to your news here :-)

Comment: UPDATE: I had to use DecelerationEnded it works exactly as i needed it to.

Comment: Okey , that's cool ! Glad that could solve this problem. :-)